# Adding press selector to DelayedConfirmationView

Tags: android, wear-os

I can't find a way to add press effect to `DelayedConfirmationView`. I tried using selector on `app:circle_color` but the pressed color doesn't appear on click.

Here are my xmls

**DelayedConfirmationView:**

```
<android.support.wearable.view.DelayedConfirmationView
    android:id="@+id/confirmation_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_close_white_48dp"
    app:circle_color="@drawable/selector_confirmation_view"
    app:circle_radius="@dimen/circular_button_radius"
    app:circle_radius_pressed="@dimen/circular_button_radius"
    app:circle_padding="6dp"
    app:circle_border_width="4dp"
    app:circle_border_color="@color/white" />
```

**Selector:**

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:color="@color/dark_blue" android:state_pressed="true" />
    <item android:color="@color/blue" />
</selector>
```

So, how do I add press effect to that view?

P.S.
It seems to work but only on `CircledImageView`

Comment: Have my answer below worked for you? Please give some feedback.

Answer (score 0):

You can see an example of usage of `DelayedConfirmationView` in official samples: `samples\android-22\wearable\DelayedConfirmation`

### Reason

`DelayedConfirmationView` is not a normal button and a pressed state is not applied by default like on standard buttons.

To listen to clicks on it there is a special `DelayedConfirmationListener` that is set via `setListener(DelayedConfirmationListener)` method. You need to implement two methods there:

- `onTimerSelected(View)` - it is triggered once user touches the button (just touch down, not even full click). Usually `DelayedConfirmationView` is started right after the it becomes visible to the user (after requesting some action for example by voice) and he has very little time to cancel this action. Reacting on touch down instead of full click is a nice way to help user interrupting this action as soon as possible.
- `onTimerFinished(View)` - called when times is finished.

### Solution

If you want to changed state to pressed on touch down you need to do following thing:

```
confirmationView.setListener(new DelayedConfirmationView.DelayedConfirmationListener() {
    @Override
    public void onTimerSelected(View view) {
        confirmationView.setPressed(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void onTimerFinished(View view) {
        // do something here
    }
});
```

---

Btw. please move your selector from `/res/drawable/` to `/res/color/` and change:

```
app:circle_color="@drawable/selector_confirmation_view"
```

to:

```
app:circle_color="@color/selector_confirmation_view"
```